# Phonegap 3.0 CLI ignoring Android app icons

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I'm using Phonegap 3.0's Command Line Interface to create and build an Android app.

In the www/res/icon/android folder, there are 4 standard Phonegap icons. I replace these with my app icons. I then build the Android project. I would expect that my icon would be generated in the platforms/android/res/drawable folder (and platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi folder etc). But instead the standard Phonegap icon is used. Is there a way to get Phonegap to use the icons in the www/res/icon/android folder rather than generating the standard icons when building an Android app?

Comment: Hmmm, according to http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens you should be able to replace the icon names in that folder. Do you have different names than for example `android/icon-36-ldpi.png`? Not sure if it would make a difference but maybe...

Answer (score 3):

When you using the command line interface you need to place the icons in the actual platform specific folders.

For android:

```
{PROJECT_PATH}/platforms/android/res/drawable/icon.png
{PROJECT_PATH}/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
{PROJECT_PATH}/platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
{PROJECT_PATH}/platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
{PROJECT_PATH}/platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
```

Comment: actually you don't have to do this if you change the icons before you add the android platform to the project. But maybe the build doesn't overwrite the files as it should.

Comment: That is correct. If you have everything in-place before adding the platform, you do not have to do this.

Comment: it's not possible to remove / add platform to fix this?

Comment: I believe it is possible to remove and re-add the platform to fix this. The only issue is if you have modified the native platform code, you will lose those revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue

PhoneGap Build is doing it correctly